Location of nontrivial Gleason parts on the topological boundary of the polydisc - Was it described anywhere else besides in Bekken's PhD Thesis?
My PhD advisor and me need the exact description of the location of the non-trivial Gleason parts on the topological boundary of the polydisc $\mathbb{D}^n$.
It was described in Otto B. Bekken's PhD Thesis called "Products of algebras on plane sets" from 1972.
The problem is that this thesis is unavailable. You can't find it on the Internet, and we also couldn't find a physical copy of it.
It really, really is very important for us, as it's a key factor needed for the paper we're working on.
All we could find was the description for the two-dimensional polydisc in "Rational Approximation on Product Sets", also by Bekken, from 1974. Here, regarding the $n$-dimensional case, it only states at the end:

Finally, we should also note that similar results to those presented here
hold for $R(X_1 \times X_2 \times \ldots \times  X_N)$ for compacts $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_N$ in $\mathbb{C}$. More details on this are in [1].

where [1] is Bekken's 1972 PhD Thesis.
For the two-dimensional case, the non-trivial Gleason parts on the topological boundary on $\mathbb{D}^2$ are located on $E_1 \times K_2$ and $K_! \times E_2$, where $E_1$ is the nullset for $R(K_2)^{\perp}$ (= measures annihilating $R(K_2)$), same goes for $E_2$ and $R(K_1)^{\perp}$.
Now, we assume that the "similar result" on the $n$-dimensional polydisc is just the cartesian product of $n-1$ discs and one nullset. But, as we write a paper which shall be published later, we need to be sure and need access to Bekken's PhD Thesis (or a similar work, which will lead to this result).
Could anyone help us maybe?

Have you contacted the math library at UCLA for assistance?  Their catalog says they have a physical copy of Bekken's thesis.

Adding to Caleb’s comment, a physical copy of this thesis is available at UCLA’s Southern Regional Library Facility (which I don’t think is the math library?). You can probably just email the library and ask if they can digitize it for you. I once obtained several otherwise unavailable papers this way. (Though I submitted my digitization request through UC’s internal system, as my institution is UCSD. But I think just emailing a request should work the same.)

(Though an entire thesis could be too long for digitization due to copyright reasons. In that case you might need to request the physical copy through an interlibrary loan, or otherwise ask someone at UC to request the physical copy and scan it for you.)
